# Intalling python-midi package in Anaconda

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, package, python-module

I'm trying to install the following [Python-Midi Package](https://pypi.org/project/python-midi/) ([GitHub link](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi)) inside an Anaconda envirorment using pip (it works fine, i've already used it for many packages) with the command `pip install python-midi`.

Unfortunately i keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: command: 'C:\Users\Mattia\anaconda3\envs\trapgenerator\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Mattia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jtz232d\\python-midi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mattia\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jtz232d\\python-midi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Mattia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jtz232d\python-midi\pip-egg-info' cwd: C:\Users\Mattia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jtz232d\python-midi\ Complete output (6 lines): Traceback (most recent call last): File "<string>", line 1, in <module> File "C:\Users\Mattia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jtz232d\python-midi\setup.py", line 42 print "No sequencer available for '%s' platform." % platform ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("No sequencer available for '%s' platform." % platform)? ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

And i can't really figure out what is the problem. Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: the package hasn't been updated for a long time. `SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'` part of the error message hints towards the package not being python3 compatible while you are trying to install with a python3 interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the mentioned python package is not compatible with Python 3, works only with Python 2